# Как отобразить два boxplot на одном графике?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

У меня есть данные, которые состоят из двух полей:

1. Остаток на счету (положительное целое число, в примере `LIMIT_BAL`).
2. Индикатор возврата предыдущего кредита (0 или 1, в примере `default`).

Я хочу сравнить данные об остатках на счету у тех, кто вернул кредит и тех, кто нет. Первый шаг — посмотреть на «ящик с усами» (boxplot).

Как самым простым образом отобразить два «ящика с усами» на одном графике один под другим?

Если просто вывести два графика^

```
sns.boxplot(x="LIMIT_BAL", hue="default", data=paid_back)
plt.show()
sns.boxplot(x="LIMIT_BAL", hue="default", data=did_not_pay_back)
plt.show()
```

То шкала не пропорциональная. Если рисовать на одном графике,

```
sns.boxplot(x="LIMIT_BAL", hue="default", data=paid_back)
sns.boxplot(x="LIMIT_BAL", hue="default", data=did_not_pay_back)
plt.show()
```

То, конечно, один график накладывается на другой.

Как выглядят данные:

```
print data[['LIMIT_BAL', 'default']].head(20)
```

Вывод:

```
    LIMIT_BAL  default
0       20000        1
1      120000        1
2       90000        0
3       50000        0
4       50000        0
5       50000        0
6      500000        0
7      100000        0
8      140000        0
9       20000        0
10     200000        0
11     260000        0
12     630000        0
13      70000        1
14     250000        0
15      50000        0
16      20000        1
17     320000        0
18     360000        0
19     180000        0
```

В примерах выше `paid_back` и `did_not_pay_back` это данные из `data`, разделенные по полую `default`.

Comment: Это не то что вам нужно - `sns.boxplot(x='default', y='LIMIT_BAL', data=data)` ?

Comment: @MaxU Да, спасибо. Видимо, перемудрил с осями, когда в первый раз пытался построить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
sns.boxplot(x='LIMIT_BAL', y='default', data=data, orient='h')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или так:

```
sns.boxplot(x='default', y='LIMIT_BAL', data=data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Хотел построить именно с горизонтальной ориентацией, но не получалось, забыл про  `orient='h'`.